# Function which returns reference to be edited in c#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to have a function return a editable reference to some internal data. Here's an example I hope helps show what I mean.

```
class foo
{
    public int value;
}

class bar
{
    bar()
    {
       m_foo = new foo();
       m_foo.value = 42;
    }
    private m_foo;
    foo getFoo(){return m_foo;}
}

class main
{
    int main()
    {
        bar b = new bar();
        b.getFoo().value = 37;
    }
}
```

The return of getFoo() according to "==" is the same as the internal m_foo until I try to edit it. In c/c++ I'd return a reference or pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your code sample, after some cleaning up, does demonstrate that when you assign 37 to value, you are changing bar's interman m_foo too.   So the answer is, your function is returning a reference type.   Now, maybe your real code is different, and it's returning not an reference type but an int, a value type, or string, a kind of special beastie...

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class foo
    {
        public int value;
    };

    public class bar
    {
        public bar()
        {
            m_foo = new foo();
            m_foo.value = 42;
        }

        private foo m_foo;
        public foo getFoo() { return m_foo; }
    };

    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main()
        {
            bar b = new bar();
            b.getFoo().value = 37;
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

More about reference vs value types:
http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're already returning the reference of `foo` in `getFoo` (this happens by default). So any changes that you make to the return value of `getFoo` will be reflected in the internal `foo` data structure in `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a property for this

```
class bar
{
    private m_foo;
    bar()
    {
       m_foo = new foo();
       m_foo.value = 42;
    }


    foo Foo
    {
    get { return m_foo;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Although my example was incorrect, this is what I was looking for I think. Thanks!

Comment: While it might be more idiomatic (and frankly: desirable) to use a property, there is no functional distinction here between a property and a method, so this won't (by itself) explain why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Blasted. I'm going to figure out how to simplified my non-working code into an example that actually breaks. Excuse me stupidity.